# Drupal quicktabs view arguments don't work

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7

I am using the quicktab module and at some tabs I pass in a view (to which I added some arguments).

I tried setting the arguments (which are 2 booleans) to 1/0 and it doesn't work, it displays all the values instead of filtering it. If I use the view in a block and set the arguments there to 1/0 it filters them properly.

Am I doing something wrong? Or does this feature not work with the quicktabs?

Answer (score 0):

I recently did the same, but instead of using the arguments of quicktabs, I used the arguments in views. Together with the context module, that suited for me. Hope this helps you :-)